# Ошибка в работе кнопки

Tags: python, tkinter

Сразу предупреждаю я новичок, в Питоне от силу неделю.

Чисто для практики делаю программу по теплофизике. Добавил решение задач по 
формуле `Q=c*m*(t2-t1)`, и тут запара.

```
entry_warming = Entry(root)
entry_warming.place(x=100, y=60)

label_warmtank = Label(root, text="c-((ДЖ)/(кг*c(в цельсиях)))")
label_warmtank.place(x=10, y=90)

entry_warmtank = Entry(root)
entry_warmtank.place(x=170, y=90)

label_mass = Label(root, text="m-(в кг)")
label_mass.place(x=10, y=120)

entry_mass = Entry(root)
entry_mass.place(x=65, y=120)

label_temperatureOne = Label(root, text="t1-(в цельсиях)")
label_temperatureOne.place(x=10, y=150)

entry_temperatureOne = Entry(root)
entry_temperatureOne.place(x=100, y=150)

label_temperatureTwo = Label(root, text="t2-(в цельсиях)")
label_temperatureTwo.place(x=10, y=180)

entry_temperatureTwo = Entry(root)
entry_temperatureTwo.place(x=100, y=180)

label_answerQ = Label(root, text="Окно вывода")
label_answerQ.place(x=100, y=210)

def warm(warming, warmtank, mass, temperatureOne, temperatureTwo):
    if warming == '':
        warming = (warmtank) * (mass) * (temperatureTwo - temperatureOne)
        anSwer = warming
        label_answerQ['text']= "Количество теплоты равно: " + str(anSwer)        
    elif warmtank == '':
        warmtank = (warming) / (mass * (temperatureTwo - temperatureOne))
        anSwer = warmtank
        label_answerQ['text']= "Удельная теплоемкость равна: " + str(anSwer) 
    elif mass == '':
        mass = (warming) / (warmtank * (temperatureTwo - temperatureOne))
        anSwer = mass
        label_answerQ['text']= "Масса равна: " + str(anSwer)    
    elif temperatureOne == '':
        temperatureOne = -(((warming) / (warmtank * mass)) - temperatureTwo)
        anSwer = temperatureOne
        label_answerQ['text']= "Начальная температура равна: " + str(anSwer)     
     elif temperatureTwo == '':
        temperatureTwo = ((warming) / (warmtank * mass)) + temperatureOne
        anSwer = temperatureTwo
        label_answerQ['text']= "Конечная температура равна: " + str(anSwer)
    else:
        label_answerQ['text']= "Ошибка"


btn_calcOne = Button(root, text="Вычислить")
btn_calcOne.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: warm(float(entry_warming.get()),
                                              float(entry_warmtank.get()),
                                              float(entry_temperatureOne.get()),
                                              float(entry_temperatureTwo.get()),
                                              float(entry_mass.get())))
btn_calcOne.place(x=100, y=240)
```

Выводит такую ошибку

> ```
> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Семён\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
> 32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
> return self.func(*args)
>   File "C:\Users\Семён\Desktop\fdsayh.py", line 74, in <lambda>
>     btn_calcOne.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: 
> warm(float(entry_warming.get()),
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
> ```

При этом в программе по решению квадратных алгоритмов аналогичный код работает на ура. Думаю что проблема в `if var = ""`, но не знаю как её решить, сначала пробовал `None`, но так тоже не работает. Помогите.

Comment: Как проблема может быть в ``if var``, если в коде такого даже нет??? Вам текст ошибки понятен?

Comment: под var я имел ввиду  if warming == '': и прочии

Comment: ну как я понял в ошибке про неправильный тип переменной. Хотя это странно ведь в похожом коде все работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как видно из вашего вопроса, ошибка здесь:

```
float(entry_warming.get())
```

Значит, в полученной строке

```
entry_warming.get()
```

что-то препятствует переводу строки на `float`.

Вероятно это будет какой-то запрещенный символ на вводе - десятичная запятая (`,`) вместо точки (`.`)? *Буква* `О` вместо *цифры* `0`?

Тоже может совсем отсутствовать ввод (т.е. на вводе будет *пустая строка*) - тогда вместо

```
float(entry_warming.get())
```

используйте например

```
float(entry_warming.get() if entry_warming.get() else 0)
```

Comment: Так я ошибку понял, он не работает при отсутствии ввода. Перевел в условии if на ноль, ввёл на месте отсутствующего значения ноль и все заработало. А можно ли как нибудь сделать чтобы при отсутствии ввода работало?

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли.

Comment: Да - я добавил это в мой ответ.

Comment: @Семён, не стоит.